# Element in a loop element

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of elements

```js
const elements = ["div", "p", "a", "span"];
```

I need a loop that will create such arranged elements for me.

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <a>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I'm stuck :) Of course, the following code does not work.

```js
const div = document.createElement(elements[0]);
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const el = document.createElement(elements[i]);
  el.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first save a reference to the outer element, then on every iteration inside the loop, reassign the *current* outer element:

```js
const elements = ["div", "p", "a", "span"];

const div = document.createElement(elements[0]);
let currentOuter = div;
for (let i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
  currentOuter = currentOuter.appendChild(document.createElement(elements[i]));
}
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

A more elegant approach would be to use `reduceRight`:

```js
const elements = ["div", "p", "a", "span"];
const div = elements.reduceRight((child, tag) => {
  const parent = document.createElement(tag);
  parent.appendChild(child);
  return parent;
}, document.createTextNode(''));

console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saw that it would be easy but I got some eclipse of mind :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elementNames = ["div", "p", "a", "span"];
let elements = elementNames.map(elementName => document.createElement(elementName));

elements = elements.map((element, index) => ({
  prev: index === 0 ? document.body : elements[index - 1],
  next: element
}))

for (let {
    prev,
    next
  } of elements) {
  prev.appendChild(next);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

p {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

a {
  background: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

span {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```